# Unit testing mails won't work when it's created with a view in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I'm starting my test with `Mail::fake();`. Then, an event triggers a listener, which sends an email:

```
Mail::send('path_to_a_view', $data, function(Message $message) {
    // set "to" and subject.
});
```

The listener implements the `ShouldQueue` interface.

In my test, I tried to check if the email was queued using `Mail::assertQueued(...);` (I've tried multiple class names for this method because I was not sure which would apply in my case).
But as that always failed, I found out that the `send` method in the `MailFake` class rejects mails which were created with a view. Responsible for that behaviour is [following line](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.5.28/src/Illuminate/Support/Testing/Fakes/MailFake.php#L281).

Why does it simply return? And how can I test if my mail was queued?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement two separate tests for what you are doing.

First test is going to test that event is fired (`Event::fake()`). Second test is going to check that if event is fired then `handle()` function on your listener queues the mail (`Mail::fake()`).

If you are just interested in checking the mail just omit implementing the first test.

> **Note**: for the second test you do not really need to dispatch the event, just resolve the listener (`resolve(FQNListener::class)->handle(new resolve(FQNEvent::class))`) and test for your mail to be queued:
>
> ```
> Mail::assertQueued(FQNMail::class)
> ```

For all this to work do not use callback as "email" but a real class. (`php artisan make:mail ...`)

---

> **Note**: also consider removing the middleman (*event+listener*) in this case if all you do is send an email.

Comment: So it's correct that callback mails are untestable!? I can hardly believe that because Laravel's developers always put emphasis on testability.

Comment: You need to understand how fakes work; they really just “fake” - for example queue - fake ::assertQueued just checks if class is in the array of classes that will be queued. So you may try to check if callback exists I guess but there is no way to distinguish between two different callbacks (need computer to verify this).

Comment: @DoeTheFourth you actually can test callbacks using "feature" tests (with log or mailtrap driver for email), after you hit the route that emits event which emits email you will have to parse manually log file to check if your email was sent (actual testing it), or hit mailtrap API. Methods/flows in actual answer are way to go because of simplicity.